# QTip efficiency, putting a QTip on 1,000 elements is very slow in IE8

Tags: jquery, qtip2

I have a page with several hundred elements which require a QTip on mouseover. This is killing IE8, though the other browsers seem to be performing alright.

To combat this, I am attempting to create the QTips when the user mouses over the element's container, so that it only does ~100-200 at a time, rather than 1,000+ all at once.

```
$('#color-family /*ID of body*/> .strctr-contain /*containing class*/').live('mouseover', function(){
   $(this).children('.palette .color-swatch, .stain-swatch, .color-swatch-dash').qtip({//foo}
})
 });
```

When you mouse over the container, this function does fire, however, when you mouse over the children, it just fires this function off over and over again, rather than displaying the tooltip.

Comment: Is it necessary to use "live" function? Are you really adding new containers dynamically?

Comment: No, I can probably just .bind()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And maybe it would be best to use "one" function, it does it all for you.

```
$('#color-family /ID of body/> .strctr-contain /containing class/').one('mouseover', function(){

     $(this).children('.palette .color-swatch, .stain-swatch, .color-swatch-dash').qti({//foo} ); 

});
```

Comment: You're welcome. There are so many functions, no one can know all of them.

Answer (score 0):

This will remove the mouseover binding when it's been run once...

```
$('#color-family /*ID of body*/> .strctr-contain /*containing class*/').on("mouseover", function(){
   $(this).children('.palette .color-swatch, .stain-swatch, .color-swatch-dash').qtip({ //foo }).off("mouseover");
});
```

It just needed the unbind (off) added to it.

Answer (score 0):

Allright, if we can use just bind function, I would try to unbind action after creating the qtips for the first time:

$('#color-family /*ID of body*/> .strctr-contain /*containing class*/').bind('mouseover', function(){

$(this).children('.palette .color-swatch, .stain-swatch, .color-swatch-dash').qtip({//foo} );
   $(this).unbind('mouseover');

});